# Check if string is in ENUM typescript

Tags: typescript

I have some emun like this

```
export enum Languages {
  nl = 1,
  fr = 2,
  en = 3,
  de = 4
}
```

and some `const language ='de';`
I only need to check does enum constraint const language, i know with array I can do
**includes** but how to check ENUM?

Also I know i can check like this

```
if (type in Languages) {
}
```

but this work is it number and not string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in order to access the enum keys followed by a simple [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
enum Languages {
  nl = 1,
  fr = 2,
  en = 3,
  de = 4,
}

const language = "de";

console.log(Object.keys(Languages).includes(language)); //true
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAMghiA5mOjgGcoG8CwAoKKEAGygF4oBGAGn0IDMAncqAJloKlBYGYPCAJsBYAWDgF98%20AMYB7EOlnFgAOmKzEACgDyAIwBWwaQBcVAa2ABPdJvhIUadAEoVASxDTiYITYBEoXycnAG4oAHowqGNGMGAgA)

This works because an [Enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html), when transpiled into JavaScript, becomes nothing more than a simple object:

```js
var Languages;
(function(Languages) {
  Languages[(Languages["nl"] = 1)] = "nl";
  Languages[(Languages["fr"] = 2)] = "fr";
  Languages[(Languages["en"] = 3)] = "en";
  Languages[(Languages["de"] = 4)] = "de";
})(Languages || (Languages = {}));

console.log(Languages);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Imagine using two _O(n)_ operations just to check if a variable is an enum member...

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it in *O(1)* ...

Given generic `invariant` function -

```
function invariant(condition: unknown, message?: string): asserts condition {
  if (condition) return
  throw Error(`Invariant violation: ${message ?? "truthy value expected"}`)
}
```

Write `invariantLanguage` using [keyof typeof Language](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-compile-time) -

```
function invariantLanguage(lang: string): asserts lang is keyof typeof Language {
  invariant(lang in Language, `"${lang}" is not a valid language`)
}
```

Now you can use `invariantLanguage` on your string input -

```
// ...

enum Language {
  nl = 1,
  fr = 2,
  en = 3,
  de = 4,
}

const x = "en"
invariantLanguage(x)
console.log(x) // : "en"

const y = "foo"
invariantLanguage(y) // ERROR Invariant violation: "foo" is not a valid language
console.log(y) // : never
```

[Verify on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMA3AhgJxusUAUECAJjLAgFyLgDWYcA7mADSIC2ApgM5foDmHAPxUuUbGD4BKKuh4dMULoiJhS5JAG8AsAChEyYIkIky8MJMSYOUEJjC79UABaZGiAKKZXmfAAMAkmhYOHiIqPAANujqVAAkGpw8-ByIgoKIAERiIM4AnmHoESApHAAeAA4c0BzEGQC+vpK6dbq6oJDqyEHYuFAAMrh8IMn4URIiYihSMnIKSmN8yEo0HLlwhlC5leuIAxLDAojael0YPXijg127gwccrL4Z8Qt1GUuI9FCI6AURMMSIBZ3RrNVo6DhgEBsG77ZJHBwfCKIAC8iAAjMwEcBMCjEAAmTEnCG4gDMhP0xBSqIALISWjpdCpRIhSriMhCMroUGcQv1biNSk0dEy4BEOAA6CJwPj4QWIAD08sQVHZYE5DOFCGZ+VRGWAcDg6u5wV6eyGI1yFkVHgASjaAPI2xCBHm9MKRaJmFX6w3vT7fX7-QH8gSMrWiiVSmWWhVKqhgDioeS6IA).

---

It is also demonstrated working properly with string enums -

```
// ...

enum Language {
  nl = 1,
  fr = 2,
  en = 3,
  de = 4,
  ja = "japanese", // also works if you have strings
}

const x = "ja"
invariantLanguage(x)
console.log(x) // : "ja"
```

Notice is does not mistake a *value* for a *key* -

```
const y = "japanese"
invariantLanguage(y) // ERROR Invariant violation: "japanese" is not a valid language
console.log(y) // : never
```

Verify on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMA3AhgJxusUAUECAJjLAgFyLgDWYcA7mADSIC2ApgM5foDmHAPxUuUbGD4BKKuh4dMULoiJhS5JAG8AsAChEyYIkIky8MJMSYOUEJjC79UABaZGiAKKZXmfAAMAkmhYOHiIqPAANujqVAAkGpw8-ByIgoKIAERiIM4AnmHoESApHAAeAA4c0BzEGQC+vpK6dbq6oJDqyEHYuFAAMrh8IMn4URIiYihSMnIKSmN8yEo0HLlwhlC5leuIAxLDAojael0YPXijg127gwccrL4Z8Qt1GUuI9FCI6AURMMSIBZ3RrNVo6DhgEBsG77ZJHBwfCKIAC8iAAjMwEcBMCjEAAmTEnCG4gDMhP0xBSqIALOTEAArH6ojKM8q4bgcDKElo6XQqUSIUq4lnoDK6FBnEL9W4jUpNHT8uARDgAOgicD4+DliAA9DrEFQRWLeQqEAL8szWeyuJzxd0pXshiNchY9R4AErugDy7sQgUlvTCkWiZkNVrAHLeMCUn2+v3+gJlAj5ZqVqvVmpduv1VAjqHkuiAA).